# XAML editor complains "Object does not match target type" for SharedResourceDictionary.Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, resourcedictionary

We use SharedResourceDictionary in our project. The dictionary is constructed from several posts here on SO. But I have reduced it to this:

```
public class SharedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public new Uri Source
    {
        get { return base.Source; }
        set { base.Source = value; }
    }
}
```

In new VS2015 the XAML designed cannot load the styles and complains

```
1. The resource "..." could not be resolved.
2. Object does not match target type.
3. The resource "..." could not be resolved.
4. The resource "..." could not be resolved.
5. The resource "..." could not be resolved.
```

in the following markup (underscored text is where it complains):

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             Style="_1_{StaticResource ...}__"
             ...
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <utils:SharedResourceDictionary _2_Source="pack://application:,,,/.../Styles.xaml"__ />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Style="_3_{StaticResource ...}__">
```

the resources and controls are in different assemblies.

Have you maybe experience the same or do know the solution?

**Update**: In fact, replacing the `utils:SharedResourceDictionary` with just the `ResourceDictionary` makes it work without error.

**Update2**: This issue is not because of `Styles.xaml` - I've created almost empty resource file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Test" Color="#FFFFFF" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and Visual Studio Design editor just complains exactly the same. And it works if I just replace `utils:SharedResourceDictionary` with `ResourceDictionary`.

**Update3**: SharedResourceDictionary is minimalistic now but XAML editor still complains.

Comment: Do any of the styles you reference have a TargetType value different to the UIElements that you are trying to apply them to?

Comment: No, basically, replacing the shared dictionary with original resource dictionary (without changing the URL) makes it work.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I have used an implementation of SharedResourceDictionary before and not had any problems with it.

Comment: @AlexAtNet I'm guessing your `SharedResourceDictionary` class is in another assembly.  Try adding the class to the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told (by a Microsoft employee) that the bug Dudu submitted (thanks!)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1820572/xaml-designer-gives-error-object-does-not-match-target-type-for-derived-resourcedictionary-property

should be fixed on update:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61f460b4-d173-45b8-8347-003e863ef074

Comment: This issue appears to *not* have been fixed in update 2 sadly.

Answer (score 2):

It might be very well an issue of VS2015; I've had issues with the XAML editor of it myself, giving errors for XAML files I've written in VS2013 and were tested and working. Try opening the project in VS2013, it **might** solve the issue. No promises on this one.

Comment: Obviously. Sadly, if it doesn't work with VS2015 due to software fault, then it just doesn't work :/

Comment: I have submitted bug on VS2015 in this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1820572/xaml-designer-gives-error-object-does-not-match-target-type-for-derived-resourcedictionary-property