# XAML designer error "Object does not match target type" for subclassed ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have inherited from `ResourceDictionary` in order to add a few custom properties to support skinning. Everything compiles and runs properly, but the VS2017 XAML designer shows the error message "Object does not match target type". The following simple class is enough to reproduce the problem:

```cs
public class SubclassedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public SubclassedResourceDictionary() : base()
    { }

    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

An interesting clue is that it only shows the exception when the custom property is referenced. The third entry shows the exception, but the second does not:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/BorderStyling.xaml"/>
<local:SubclassedResourceDictionary Source="Styles/BorderStyling.xaml"/>
<local:SubclassedResourceDictionary ExtraInfo="foo" Source="Styles/BorderStyling.xaml"/>
```

[image]

Normally I'd ignore this as yet-another-designer-bug, but my real code also implements the `ISupportInitialize` interface which throws exceptions to warn the developer about invalid combinations of the custom properties. Those exceptions are never shown, which at least tells me the target-type exception happens before my code runs.

I'm wondering if the collection used to store resources has code that only accepts "real" `ResourceDictionary` objects. I've encountered this whether the subclass is referenced in a `MergedDictionary` list or other resource lists such as `<Window.Resources>`. But, again, it actually builds and runs, so if that's the problem, perhaps it's specific to designer validation?

The problem appears similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726759/xaml-editor-complains-object-does-not-match-target-type-for-sharedresourcedict) issue from 2015, but the accepted answer only says that it's a bug that will be fixed (followed by a comment stating that it wasn't fixed). Same bug? Any work-arounds?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932039/object-does-not-match-target-type-in-designdata/3053721#3053721) answer which sounds like it could be related, but I haven't been able to figure out how to try it. VS2017 doesn't appear to provide access to the designer files except in the file view (not solution view, where one could modify the properties).

Comment: in designer window enable project code

Comment: @UsmanAli it already is, but thanks. It's sort of intresting, though -- my real code adds several custom properties. With project code enabled, it only highlights the first extra property. If I disable project code it highlights all of the extra properties with that same error message.